# TrueCrypt: Encrypt Dual-Boot System Using 2 Separate Hard Drives

Tags: windows, truecrypt

I know Google points to many different guides, tutorials and explanations regarding different variations and setups for encrypting multi-boot systems, but (quite surprisingly) I haven't found one which details my exact setup, or one similar enough.

I have 2 separate hard drives (A and B), with Windows 7 installed on each of them (Win7 on A, Win7 on B). 
My boot loader is on drive A, so during boot I can choose to boot from drive B instead.

My question is: can I choose "Encrypt the whole drive" and encrypt drive B, so that I will be prompted by TrueCrypt for my password if and only when I choose to boot from drive B, after arriving at drive A's boot loader.

If this is not possible, I have to go with the solution detailed here:
http://www.7tutorials.com/how-encrypt-your-system-drive-truecrypt-multi-boot-configuration
in which case I will have to press ESC once I get to the TrueCrypt boot loader if I want to boot from drive A.

In the end, I want users to see a seemingly regular Windows boot loader (residing on drive A), with the choice of two OSes to boot from (one OS on A, and another on B), and only once they choose to boot from the second option (drive B), will they be faced with the TrueCrypt password prompt.

Comment: The problem is, Windows can't read OS information on your encrypted "B" drive, so it can't boot something that seemingly doesn't exist.

Comment: @NathanC But the TC bootloader isn't encrypted. This sounds possible provided the standard Win bootloader offers handing off boot process to another disk (chainloading) and possibly TC understands its position as on 2nd disk?

Comment: Is there a way I can check if this is possible without causing any permanent/unrecoverable damage?

Comment: @Jason, Did you ever figure out how to accomplish this?  I've got the exact same question...